# HOw to get CSV value for following scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here's my current table data.

```
AccountNumber         Product
------------------------------
00505871              Product1
00505871              Product2
00503297              Product3
00900004              Product4
00505871              Product3
00514884              Product3
00503297              Product2
00505871              Product1
```

How can I achieve following result.

```
AccountNumber        ProductString
------------------------------------------------
00505871             Product1,Product2,Product3
00503297             Product2,Product3
00900004             Product4
00514884             Product3
```

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select AccountNumber, 
       stuff((select ',' + Product 
                  from YourTable t2 
                  where t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber 
                  order by Product 
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as ProductString
    from YourTable t1
    group by AccountNumber
```

Comment: This gives result, but I want distinct product for each account.

Comment: @ashish.chotalia: As you've demonstrated in the answer you posted independently, it is simply a matter of adding the `distinct` keyword to the solution I gave you.

Answer (score -2):

Below solution worked for me.

## 1.

```
select AccountNumber, 
       stuff((select ',' + Product 
                  from YourTable t2 
                  where t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber 
      Group by Product 
                  order by Product          
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as ProductString
    from YourTable t1
    group by AccountNumber
```

## 2.

```
select AccountNumber,   
       stuff((select distinct ',' +Product
                  from YourTable t2   
                  where t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber   
                  group by Product   
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'') as ProductString  
    from YourTable t1  
    group by AccountNumber
```

Comment: -1. You had a perfectly usable answer from someone else. Why take their answer, tweak it slightly, then post your own and accept it rather than asking him to tweak his own?

Comment: @Adam, you can see time stamp there, Here are the two methods that I came across. I thought it might be useful to community that's the reason to mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you posted it a day after Joe posted his answer. Just adding the `distinct` keyword to his query would have worked. You should only post (and accept) your own answer if there are no usable answers.

Comment: Ok fine I am making his answer as selected :)