# Stored procedure: Return column values as comma separated values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator)

So i have this model, [picture of my db model](http://picpaste.com/model-1OEkgOhr.png)

and i want to create a stored procedure that, given a calendarEvent id, it returns the usernames of all domainusers attending to it in a comma separated string.

I can get the affected usernames in a table form easily with a join, but how do i kinda flatten that table?

Comment: I think i can get to my solution with the question you linked

Comment: You can also use the STUFF command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713476/how-to-get-csv-value-for-following-scenario